# SQL Server Analysis Services Account Name is missing

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2012 on Windows Server 2012, but when I get to: 
[image]

The SQL Server Analysis Services are empty so I can't continue instalation proces. Any idea what Account Name should be there? And how to add it?

Comment: I'm coming across the same thing while trying to install SQL Server 2012 on Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why a default is missing, but this is a service account, so as with any other service account, best practice is to create a user in AD for this purpose only and to assign this user account (making sure it has sufficient permissions on the local machine where SSAS is running) to the SSAS service on installation.

Answer (score 0):

The MSA(Managed Service Account) must be created in the Active Directory by the domain administrator before SQL Server setup can use it for SQL Server services.

Check here ~ [Configure Windows Service Accounts and Permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)